# Insert a Row using execute Immediate

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

The below pl/sql showing error, because of the quotes. Can you please help ? And can you give me tips how to write this type of queries.

```
DECLARE 
v_RULE_NAME VARCHAR2(200):='ABC';
v_user_id NUMBER:=2;
begin
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO BW_TXS 
                 VALUES ('||TXN_ID.NEXTVAL||','||v_user_id||','
                         ||SYSDATE||',''super '''||v_RULE_NAME
                         ||',''super '''||v_RULE_NAME||')';

end;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

it should be like:

```
DECLARE 
v_RULE_NAME VARCHAR2(200):='ABC';
v_user_id NUMBER:=2;
begin
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO BW_TXS 
                 VALUES (TXN_ID.NEXTVAL,'||v_user_id||',SYSDATE,''super '||v_RULE_NAME
                         ||''',''super '||v_RULE_NAME||''')';

end;
/
```

but please, when using dynamic SQL , use bind variables (in this simple case though, dynamic SQL is total overkill). i.e.

```
DECLARE 
v_RULE_NAME VARCHAR2(200):='ABC';
v_user_id NUMBER:=2;
begin
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO BW_TXS 
                 VALUES (TXN_ID.NEXTVAL,:userid,SYSDATE,:rule, :rule)'
 using v_user_id, 'super ' || v_rule_name, 'super ' || v_rule_name;

end;
/
```

(not sure why you have the same string in two columns). without dynamic SQL in this trivial case is possible with:

```
DECLARE 
v_RULE_NAME VARCHAR2(200):='ABC';
v_user_id NUMBER:=2;
begin
  INSERT INTO BW_TXS 
  VALUES (TXN_ID.NEXTVAL,v_user_id,SYSDATE, 'super ' || v_rule_name, 
          'super ' || v_rule_name);

end;
/
```

also you should always define column names in your insert like `insert into bw_txt (a, b, c, d..) values (...)` as if someone adds a column with a default value later, your code will break.

Comment: Yah! Executed success. Thank you. Can you rewrite the query using bind variables. And can you explain me what is use of bind variables. Because i need to migrate code from sql server to oracle, but i am new to oracle world. Need help.

Comment: @user1990383 the bind ones are shown above. the use of bind variables (a) prevents sql injection attacks (b) prevents you flooding your shared pool with similar sql statements [i.e. they improve performance and prevent possible shared pool memory errors] (c) reduces CPU load on the box due to sabving on excess hard parsing. Don't use dynamic SQL unless you need to (static SQL is faster and you don't have to worry about bind variables when using static SQL

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your response. Really, I wonder because people who know me always behind me don't show interest to help, but without knowing people you are helping. God bless YOU.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for execute immediate.  That is one of the benefits of PL/SQL, persistence operations such as inserts, updates and deletes are very simple.

```
DECLARE 
v_RULE_NAME VARCHAR2(200):='ABC';
v_user_id NUMBER:=2; 

begin 

insert into BW_TXS VALUES(TXN_ID.NEXTVAL, v_user_id, SYSDATE, 'super', 'super', v_RULE_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why but I found I had to wrap in a block otherwise I just got bizaare error messages:

```
execute immediate '
  begin 
          insert into something.SomethingElse (...)
          values (SYSDATE,''1.58.0.0'',''f1a87dfbe1ba'',1,null);
  end;';
```

The error message I had was:

```
Error report:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at line 14
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

Comment: Delete symbol ";" within of the sentence